# DOMPDF no carga php

Tags: php, dompdf

Estoy generando archivos(facturas) en pdf con DOMPDF, efectivamente convierte a pdf, pero lo que tengo en php no lo muestra, mi código es este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img
      src="http://www.supah.it/dribbble/017/logo.png"
      width="32" height="32" alt="logo" border="0" />
    </td>
    <?php $saludo = 'Hola'; echo $saludo; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

el cual me genera esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver, me genera el pdf pero omite lo que tenga en php, estoy trabajando con php 5.4, gracias

Comment: No sé por qué tienes una etiqueta `</td>` huérfana, cuando no hay ni `<table>` ni `<tr>`. Prueba a quitar esa etiqueta y a poner la variable así: `$saludo = <p>'Hola</p>'`

Comment: Tienes razón, se me fue de más ese "td", pero eso no soluciona mi problema

Comment: ¿Cómo estás generando el PDF? Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código correspondiente.